# Context-Free Grammar from this language

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

I'm having difficulties with an exercise in a theoretical CS class.
The problem is:

let $L_{2}$ be a language defined as follows: after every "a" come atleast two "b" or after every "b" comes atleast one "a".

What is the CFG that creates $L_{2}$?

I'm struggling since 2h... I've found out that for example "abba" is not in the language, but to write it formally is quite difficult. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome come to [cs.SE]! The condition is not clear enough for me. Suppose the alphabet only has $a$ and $b$.  What would be the last symbol in a word in $L_2$? If it is $a$, no $b$ follows it. If its $b$, no $a$ follows it. So there is no non-empty word in $L_2$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually $L_{2} = \{\omega \in \{a,b\}^*...$  and then the the condition like I wrote in the beginning. It also states that "b", "abbbbbabb", "aaaabaaaba" also "$\epsilon$" are in the language. ( the term is {a,b}^*, but I suck at formatting...sry first time)

Comment: @apass: I assume that by "or" they mean "or", rather than "and" (which is how you appear to have interpreted it). So every non-empty word in the language satisfies one of the two predicates (since, as you say, it's impossible for a non-empty word to satisfy both).

Comment: @rici yes, that is correct !! It's "or", not "and".

Comment: @rici, thanks. My bad (lunch saturation). Consider language $L_3$, in each word of which every $a$ is followed by at least two $b$'s. Can you construct CFG for $L_3$? Consider the language $L_4$, in each word of which every $b$ is followed by at least one $a$. Can you construct CFG for L_4? In fact, $L_3$ and $L_4$ are regular languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Aspass.Jack wrote in the comments, let's first define $L_3$ to be the language where each $a$ is followed by at least 2 $b$'s, and $L_4$ to be the language where each $b$ is followed by at least one $a$.

Now, if let's say you can define CFGs for $L_3$ and $L_4$ with start symbols $S_3$ and $S_4$. Then, we simply need to define a grammer with the transition:
$$S \rightarrow S_3|S_4$$
together with all the transitions from the other 2 CFGs. Hopefully this simplifies your problem.